# String replacement in math mode

Tags: xstring, substitution

Writing a path in a graph as `$a-b-c$` will not typeset as nicely as `$a\text{-}b\text{-}c$`, so I'm trying to create a macro that performs some string substitution. I tried using `xstring`, but unfortunately it doesn't appear to work in math mode. E.g.,

```
\StrSubstitute{a-b-c}{-}{\text{-}}
```

works fine, but

```
$\StrSubstitute{a-b-c}{-}{\text{-}}$
```

will fail. What would be the best way to create a macro `\mpath` so that I could simply write `$\mpath{a-b-c}$`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a great use case for the Expl3 sequence commands. Here's your macro using those:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mpath}{m}{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {-} {#1} % ❶
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {{-}} % ❷
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

First, ❶ we split the argument into a sequence using `-` as the delimiter. `\l_tmpa_seq`¹ will be a sequence with each bit of text separated by `-` in a separate item in the sequence.

Then, ❷ we consume the sequence by joining the elements back together and dumping that in the output.²

---

1. Helpfully provided by default for our temporary use.
2. I don't think that `\text{-}` is really what you want. I'm guessing you weren't happy with the binop spacing around `-` in math mode, so I simply put in `{-}` which treats the - as an ordinary symbol rather than a binary operator and there's no extra spacing there.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. :)

Answer (score 7):

You might do

```
\newcommand{\mpath}[1]{%
  \begingroup\noexpandarg
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{-}{\text{-}}%
  \endgroup
}
```

so to inhibit the full expansion of arguments performed by `xstring`.

A simple solution with just primitives. Take your pick

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mpathminus}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \mathcode`-=\numexpr\mathcode`- - "2000\relax
  #1%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\mpathendash}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \mathcode`-=123
  #1
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\mpathemdash}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \mathcode`-=124
  #1
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

$\mpathminus{a-b-c}$

$\mpathendash{a-b-c}$

$\mpathemdash{a-b-c}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the spacing doesn't seem really good, so you can do better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mpathhyphen}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { - } { \mspace{2mu}{\operatorname{-}}\mspace{1mu} }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mpathminus}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { - } { {-} }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mpathendash}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { - } { \mspace{2mu}{\operatorname{--}}\mspace{1mu} }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mpathemdash}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { - } { \mspace{2mu}{\operatorname{---}}\mspace{1mu} }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\mpathhyphen{a-b-c}$

$\mpathminus{a-b-c}$

$\mpathendash{a-b-c}$

$\mpathemdash{a-b-c}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here we exploit `\operatorname` changing the mathcode of `-` into producing a real hyphen (or ligatures if combined).

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It defines a LaTeX macro called `\mpath`, which replaces all instances of `-` with en-dashes with the help of Lua's powerful `string.gsub` string function.

Note that typographic en-dashes are slightly thinner and are spaced more tightly than mathord-type "minus" symbols. If you'd rather have thicker lines and looser spacing, just replace `\\mbox{--}` with `{-}` in the third argument of `string.gsub`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mpath[1]{\directlua{%
    tex.sprint(( string.gsub( "#1" , "-" , "\\mbox{--}" )) )}}
   
\begin{document}
$\mpath{a-b-c}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple token cycle.

The `{}{}{}` in the definition tells the cycle to "ignore groups, ignore macros, and ignore spaces," which should not occur in the argument anyhow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle,amsmath}
\newcommand\mpath[1]{\tokcycle{\ifx-##1\text{-}\else##1\fi}{}{}{}{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\mpath{a-b-c}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a `listofitems` approach, in which the list is parsed at `-` tokens, and regurgitated, with `\text{-}` being inserted at the point of the separators.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,amsmath}
\setsepchar{-}
\newcommand\mpath[1]{\readlist\pathlist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\pathlist[]{\ifnum\zcnt=1\else\text{-}\fi\z}}
\begin{document}
$\mpath{a-b-c}$
\end{document}
```