# How to auto replace string pattern in header CSV cells with pgfplotstable?

Tags: pgfplotstable, strings, csv

In the following csv file example, I want to automatically replace a string pattern in all headers cells when importing with `pgfplotstable`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.csv}
    parameter,cubic parameter,revised parameter,"$quartic_{parameter}$"
    1 ,13 ,34 ,5
    2 ,3  ,7  ,11
\end{filecontents*}
```

I want to replace the pattern "*parameter*" by "*param*" in all header cells.

I tried this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.csv}
    parameter,cubic parameter,revised parameter,"$quartic_{parameter}$"
    1 ,13 ,34 ,5
    2 ,3  ,7  ,11
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,row sep=newline,ignore chars={"},string replace*={parameter}{param}]{sample.csv}%
\end{document}
```

I obtained this result (no expected changes in the headers cell):
[image]

I would prefer this result where all the "*parameter*" words have been replaced by the string "*param*" even in "math mode" (last column header):

[image]

Is there a way to do that automatically in all header cells with `pgfplotstable` (I would prefer to use `pgfplotstable` but I am open to other solutions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option `assign column name` of `pgfplotstable` package.
Two alternative solutions follow.

*Fist solution*
With the macro `\mpath` taken from this [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604009/101651) (pay attention, this should be compiled with LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604009/101651:
\newcommand\mpath[1]{\directlua{%
    tex.sprint(( string.gsub( "#1" , "parameter" , "param" )) )}}
   
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.csv}
    parameter,cubic parameter,revised parameter,"$quartic_{parameter}$"
    1 ,13 ,34 ,5
    2 ,3  ,7  ,11
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, row sep=newline,  ignore chars={"},
    header=has colnames,
    assign column name/.style={
            /pgfplots/table/column name={\mpath{#1}}},
    ]{sample.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Second solution*
Are you sure you like the last column header written in italics?
Isn't it better in the following way?
The following code uses `\StrSubstitute` from `xstring` package for string headers. The column header in math mode is modified explicitly with the option `columns` of `pgfplotstable` package.
It can be compiled with the ordinary pdfLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{amsmath}
   
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.csv}
    parameter,cubic parameter,revised parameter,"$quartic_{parameter}$"
    1 ,13 ,34 ,5
    2 ,3  ,7  ,11
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, row sep=newline,  ignore chars={"},
    header=has colnames,
    assign column name/.style={
        /pgfplots/table/column name={\StrSubstitute{#1}{parameter}{param}}},
    columns/$quartic_{parameter}$/.style={column name={quartic$_{\text{param}}$}},
    ]{sample.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image]